# How does Spring Boot get the local server properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using the Spring Boot to develop a application. When startup a spring boot application, I got a log message like

```
com.xerox.eppic.report.Application       : Starting Application on {{server name}} with PID {{PID}}
```

I want to know, how does Spring Boot get my server information? I need this information to develop some other features.

I have added the line number to log message, the line number for my main class is not correct. I have read some source code of Spring Boot, I didn't find where Spring Boot read the server info.

Comment: I'm guessing it uses: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html ... but you should probably check out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class responsible of this is `StartupInfoLogger`. Check [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/StartupInfoLogger.java#L110) for more details.

In short the server name is retrieved by the `INetAddress` class and the `PID` system property is set by [`ApplicationPid`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationPid.java)